# How to launch a node with a parameter in ROS2 dashing?

Tags: ros2

While I was looking for a solution, I came across a solution for ROS2 crystal on this post [How to launch a node with a parameter in ROS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917469/how-to-launch-a-node-with-a-parameter-in-ros2).

Unfortunately, that does not seem to work under ROS2 dashing. I created a fork of the ROS2 realsense driver (https://github.com/AndreasAZiegler/ros2_intel_realsense/tree/serial_no_param/realsense_ros2_camera) and my goal is to be able to pass the serial number via a parameter. With

```
ros2 run realsense_ros2_camera realsense_ros2_camera  __params:=/paht/to/config/parameters.yaml
```

passing the parameter works fine but when I start the node with the launch python file

```
ros2 launch realsense_ros2_camera ros2_intel_realsense.launch.py
```

it ignores the parameter. The path to the parameters.yaml is correct (I print it in the launch python script).

Answer (score 1):

In your launch file, you change the node name to: `node_name='realsense_ros2_camera'`

However the default name of the node and also the name you use in the config file is `RealSenseCameraNode` which is why it works when you're running it from the cmd-line (not passing a new name).

```
# RealSense parameters
---

RealSenseCameraNode_ns:
    RealSenseCameraNode:
      ros__parameters:
        serial_no: 845112070204
```

Change it to

```
# RealSense parameters
---

RealSenseCameraNode_ns:
  realsense_ros2_camera:
    ros__parameters:
      serial_no: 845112070204
```

And it should work (or keep the default name in the launch file as well). Minor thing: I change the yaml config to only be 2 spaces for each new row, not sure it matters.