# Dynamically setting a ROS2 parameter using launch file?

Tags: python, ros2

There are a bunch of resources that describes setting a parameter on node startup using a launch file.( [How to launch a node with a parameter in ROS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917469/how-to-launch-a-node-with-a-parameter-in-ros2))

However this will not trigger the dynamic reconfigure callback: `set_on_parameters_set_callback` . Is there any way to specify an action in the launch file on a node that triggers this callback ?

Equivalent of running a `ros2 param set ...` command (which would trigger the callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the ROS 2 service `/<node name>/set_parameters` to trigger this callback. E.g. `/talker/set_parameters` for the talker node in the `demo_nodes_cpp` package.

Create a shell script containing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ros2 service call /<node name>/set_parameters <service type> <your parameters>
```

...and add it to your launch file.